# Hbase BulkLoad without mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, bulk-load

I'm wondering if it is possibile to write a java program that do a BulkLoad on HBase. I'm on a hadoop cluster but I don't need to write a MapReduce Job for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BulkLoad works with HFile. So If you have HFiles, you can directly use LoadIncrementalHFiles to handle the bulk load.
Generally we use Map reduce, which can convert the data into above format, and perform Bulk Load.
If you have csv file, you can use ImportTsv utility to process your data into HFiles. use [this link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_hbase_import.html#concept_mnj_psz_wp_unique_1), for more information
It depends at which format you data is in currently. 
Point to note is, Bulk Load, do not use Write ahead Logs(WAL). They skip this step and add data at a faster rate. if you have any other framework depending on the above WAL, consider other options of adding data in Hbase. Happy Coding.

Comment: I have a large amount of small PDF files (2m+) and I would insert them into HBase. I've tried with direct puts but I encounter WAL problems. So I'd like to use BulkLoad, but I can't use mapreduce becouse I can't move that files on HDFS, I would saturate all the Inodes because they are a very large number of small files.

Comment: Please add your question :). I am assuming, you want to add lot of pdf files into Hbase, and tried to use put but did not succeed. So you want to use bulk load but not with mapreduce. So want an alternate solution. In short for - many pdf, hbase storage, bulk load, no mapreduce. Am I right